# Proof that $X \subseteq Y$ if and only if $X \cup Y = Y$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This exercise (2.1.49) was taken from [An Infinite Descent into Pure Mathematics](http://infinitedescent.xyz).

#### Question

Let $X, Y$ be sets. Prove that $X \subseteq Y$ if and only if $X \cup Y = Y$.

#### Proof

Towards a contradiction, assume $X \not \subseteq Y$ if and only if $X \cup Y = Y$.

For $X \not \subseteq Y$, then $X$ must be non-empty and contain a set of elements, $N$ such that $N$ is disjoint with $Y$. Therefore, assume $X = \{x : x \in Y \vee x \in N\}$.

For $X \cup Y = Y$, $N = \{\}$. This is a contradiction with the assumption that $N$ is inhabited. Therefore, the assumption $X \subseteq Y$ if and only if $X \cup Y = Y$ cannot be true. We have shown that $X \subseteq Y$ if and only if $X \cup Y = Y$. $\Box$

Is this proof rigorous enough, and are there any improvements that can be made?

Comment: The negation of '$X \subset Y$ iff $X \cup Y=Y$' is not '$X$ not a  subset $Y$ iff $X \cup Y=Y$'

Comment: What do you mean by "let $X = \{x : x \in X \vee x \in N\}$"? Clearly $X = \{x : x \in X\}$.

Comment: @Bungo I meant $x \in Y$. I will update the question.

Comment: "assume $X = \{x : x \in Y \vee x \in N\}$ is the same as "assume $X = Y \cup N$", which (assuming $N$ nonempty) is the same as "assume $X \subsetneq Y$". This is not the same as $X \not\subseteq Y$.

Comment: @Bungo Would it make sense if I instead wrote $X = \{x : x \in (X \cap Y) \vee x \in N\}$. Or is that circular as well?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer today, but the biggest issue is by using this set $N$ it in your proof, you are asserting its existence and properties without proof, and proving the existence of such an $N$ is no less amount of work than completing the proof in a more direct manner. For one direction, assume $X \cup Y = Y$, and suppose $x \in X$. Your job is to fill in the logic until you get to the conclusion $x \in Y$. This will prove $X \cup Y = Y \implies X \subseteq Y$.

Comment: There's no reason to seek a proof by contradiction. To prove an $\iff$ statement, prove each direction $\implies$ and $\impliedby$. Both are straightforward here.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I didn't realize that $N$ I was creating would result in a circular proof. I'll try to prove this directly, rather than using a contradiction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove a statement of the form $A \iff B$, you need to show that both implications $A \implies B$ and $B \implies A$ hold. I will sketch both directions but leave a few details for you to fill in.

> First let's prove $X \subseteq Y \implies X \cup Y = Y$.

To do this, we assume that $X \subseteq Y$, and we need to prove that $X \cup Y = Y$. To prove equality of two sets, we need to prove containment in both directions: namely $X \cup Y \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X \cup Y$.

To prove the first containment $X \cup Y \subseteq Y$, start with the assumption $X \subseteq Y$. This implies that $X \cup Y \subseteq Y \cup Y$ (why?), and of course $Y \cup Y = Y$, so we conclude that $X\cup Y \subseteq Y$ as desired.

The second containment $Y \subseteq X \cup Y$ is always true and doesn't even require the assumption that $X \subseteq Y$ (why?)

> Now let's prove $X \cup Y = Y \implies X \subseteq Y$.

So, assume that $X \cup Y = Y$. The containment $X \subseteq X \cup Y$ always holds (why?). By the assumption, the RHS of this containment equals $Y$. Thus $X \subseteq Y$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be an arbritary element in $X$. Then,

$$x \in X \cup Y.$$
Also,
$$ X \cup Y = Y \implies x \in Y.$$

Since $\forall x \in X,\ x \in Y$, $X \subseteq Y.\tag1$

Let $y$ be an arbritary element in  $X \cup Y$. Then,

$$X \cup Y = Y \implies y \in Y$$

Since $\forall y \in X \cup Y,\ y \in Y,$ 
$$\begin{aligned} X \cup Y \subseteq Y \\
\implies X \subseteq Y \end{aligned}\tag2$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$,

$$X \subseteq Y \iff X \cup Y = Y.\ \blacksquare$$

Comment: You have proved $\impliedby$ only.

Comment: @AdityaSingh Checking this would make a good proof verification question on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Below a visually organized proof in two columns, one for each direction ( of the biconditional that has to be proved)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $X,Y$ be sets.

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $X\subseteq Y$. First we show that $X\cup Y\subseteq Y$. Let $x\in X\cup Y$.

Case 1. $x\in X$. If $x\in X$, then $x\in Y$ since $X\subseteq Y$. Thus $X\cup Y\subseteq Y$.

Case 2. $x\in Y$. If $x\in Y$ then we are done. Again $X\cup Y\subseteq Y$.

So we conclude that $X\cup Y\subseteq Y$.

Now we show that $Y\subseteq X\cup Y$. Let $x\in Y$. Since $x\in Y$, $x\in X\cup Y$. So we conclude that $Y\subseteq X\cup Y$. We've shown that  $X\cup Y\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X\cup Y$, so $Y = X\cup Y$.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose $X\cup Y = Y$. We need to show that $X\subseteq Y$. Let $x\in X$. Since $x\in X$, $x\in X\cup Y$. Since $X\cup Y = Y$, we have $x\in Y$. So $X\subseteq Y$ which is what we needed to show.

Thus $X\subseteq Y$ iff $X\cup Y = Y$.

QED